# Test class For Standard Apex controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am Getting

> Error System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

in Test class For newservice object , It will create new service implicitly by trigger

Controller Class

```
public class ShowMobileNumberControllerForService{

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public String getMobileNumberList() {
        return null;
    }


    public String serviceId {get;set;}
    Public Boolean ShowpageBlockFlag{get;set;}
    public Service__c serviceData {get;set;}
    public List<Service__c> MobileNumberDetails {get;set;}
    public Date activityDate = System.Today();
    public Id loggedInUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    public ShowMobileNumberControllerForService(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

      // serviceId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');


       serviceId = 'a0bO000000BWMpo'; 

        serviceData = new Service__c();      


        String queryString = GeneralUtilityClass.getQueryString('Service__c');
        queryString = queryString + 'FROM Service__c WHERE Id = :serviceId';

        serviceData = dataBase.query(queryString);       

        System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@'+queryString);  

        MobileNumberDetails= [SELECT Id, Mobile_1__c,Mobile_2__c,Whats_App_Number__c,Stage__c,Sub_Stage__c From Service__c WHERE Id=:serviceId ];
        ShowpageBlockFlag = false;



    }


    Boolean isError = FALSE;

    public PageReference cancel() {
        PageReference pref = new PageReference('/'+serviceId );
        pref.setRedirect(true);
        return pref;
    }
    Public void ShowBlockMethod()
    {
    ShowpageBlockFlag = true;
    }





}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public Class ShowMobileNumberForService_Test{

    private static Task newTask;
    private static User newUser;
    private static Account newAccount;
    private static property__c newProperty;
    private static Service__c newservice;
    private static Opportunity newopportunity;

 private static void init() {

          newAccount = InitializeTestData.createAccount();
          database.insert(newAccount);

          newUser = InitializeTestData.createUser('cgpet00D900000010QJQ.test@demmo.com.test');
          Database.insert(newUser);

          newProperty = InitializeTestData.createProperty(newAccount.Id);
          newProperty.Is_Service_Created__c=True;
          database.insert(newProperty);


          newopportunity=InitializeTestData.VCOpportunity(newAccount.Id);
          newopportunity.Sub_Stage__c ='VC Given';
          newopportunity.Stage__c ='Closed Won';  
          newopportunity.Status__c='Closed';
          newopportunity.Property__c=newProperty.Id;
          database.insert(newopportunity);


       }

         private static Testmethod void serviceTest()
      { 
        Test.startTest();

         init();

         **newservice =[select Id from Service__c where Opportunity__c=:newopportunity.Id];**


         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(newservice);
         ShowMobileNumberControllerForService testAccPlan = new ShowMobileNumberControllerForService(sc);

          PageReference pageRef = Page.ServiceShowMobileNoPage; //  VF page Name         
          pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(newservice.Id));       
          Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

          testAccPlan.cancel();


        Test.StopTest();
     }



}
```

Comment: What it the querysyring that is generated?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems here.

One, in your main class, you hard-code an Id value. That Id will not be visible in text context:

```
   serviceId = 'a0bO000000BWMpo'; 
   String queryString = GeneralUtilityClass.getQueryString('Service__c');
   queryString = queryString + 'FROM Service__c WHERE Id = :serviceId';

   serviceData = dataBase.query(queryString);
```

Your code should not be dependent upon the existence of specific Ids. That will make it fragile and very difficult to test.

Second, you're relying on some trigger functionality that we're not shown here to ensure that a `Service__c` record is being created. That seems not to be working, but it should be validated in a test of the trigger handler itself.

Your `init()` method looks like it may be suppressing this functionality:

```
      newProperty.Is_Service_Created__c=True;
```